# Profiles - different or not?

Tags: support, area-51, profile-page, merge-accounts

I have posted to different sites (Ask Different, Tex, Stack Overflow, and now Area 51) but on the Area 51 photo (after I commit) only my Stack Overflow reputation score is shown.

Now, are these two different profiles or not?

https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/52198/rainer

https://stackexchange.com/users/316310/rainer

If yes, how can I merge them? Because when I follow 
https://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts it tells me that they are not valid profile pages?

Comment: [This](https://stackexchange.com/users/316310/rainer) is your network profile, it is not an account.

Comment: As for flair, it's showing only sites where you have more than 200 reputation, and you have it only on SO.

Comment: Thanks - this answers my question. So I have one with stack exchange, and one network profile for each community? And the second one concerning the "flair" clarifies things as well. If this would be an answer, I would accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Stack Exchange consists of over 100 different communities aka sites.

Each community got its own website, its own repository of posts, and its own set of user accounts, [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/52198/rainer) for example is your user profile on "Ask Different" community.

When a user creates an account in one of Stack Exchange sites (aka communities) for the first time, he is also assigned a "Network Profile", which is not a real account just a place where information from all profiles on all sites is being kept. [This](https://stackexchange.com/users/316310/rainer) is your network profile which can't be merged as it's not an account.

As for Area51 flair, it's showing only sites where you have more than 200 reputation, that's why you see only Stack Overflow.